# Keith Wood jQuery iCalendar

Tags: jquery, google-calendar-api, icalendar

Has anyone used Keith Wood's jQuery iCalendar plugin before [Pluggin](http://keith-wood.name/icalendar.html) and managed to get it to add 'all-day' events? 
I removed out the times and just did dates but it just defaults to 12:00am when I do - I need it to be an all-day event instead (no time)
I had a look through the documentation on his site and the only reference to days rather than times seems to be for recurring events from what I can see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just updating this one incase anyone else looking for the same thing.. I got in touch with the author about my query and this is what he came back with..

"The plugin doesn't support all-day events directly, since it doesn't provide a duration option. The best you can do is have start be yyyy-mm-dd 00:00:00 and end be yyyy-mm-dd 23:59:59."

Just FYI!